# Why MediaPlaybackItem does not have TimedMetadataTracks?

Tags: c#, uwp

I have two uwp desktop applications with tts features. In both I have the same code snippet. The problem is that in one of them the MediaPlaybackItem created contains TimedMetadataTracks and the other does not. Any help is most welcome.

```
            SpeechSynthesisStream synthesisStream = await WTMVariables.Synthesizer.SynthesizeTextToStreamAsync(tbxOriginalText.Text);
            var mediaSource = MediaSource.CreateFromStream(synthesisStream, synthesisStream.ContentType);
            var mediaPlaybackItem = new MediaPlaybackItem(mediaSource);

            string strTranslatedText = "";

            if (mediaPlaybackItem.TimedMetadataTracks[0].Label == "SpeechSentence")
            {
                foreach (SpeechCue cue in mediaPlaybackItem.TimedMetadataTracks[0].Cues)
                {
                    if (cue != null)
                    {
                        if (cue.Text.Trim() != "")
                        {
                           //Do something;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: Are you testing both of the apps in the same scenario?

Comment: Yea! Even on the same machine and with the same text for conversion.

Comment: That's interesting. Do you have another devices to test to see if it works?